# How can I point two different projects to the same SQLite db-file?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, .net-core

I have a simple question. I have 2 layers in my application, a front-end and data access layer, in different projects. I am creating a sqlite db in the data access layer by migration in data access layer and now I want to use a connection string. I am creating a context in the data access layer like this:

```
public class TodoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Activity> Activieties { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=todo.db");
    }
}
```

Looks simple right, db is created in data access layer project. But when I run front end project program is looking for a db but in a front end project folder.I have checke that by adding:

```
 var test = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

In above method. Also when I modify connection string to direct path like:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TodoList\TodoDataAccess\todo.db");
    }
```

It works, so my question is what can I do to change it?

Comment: Use relative path to well known location

Comment: Ha! Your code helped me connect to an Sqlite database that I have been trying to connect for 4 days!  Your line and syntax that referenced absolute path worked for me: ............optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TodoList\TodoDataAccess\todo.db");...........I will work on relative path later. Now I can do some developing instead of hair pulling. (what is weird is that in my startup.cs it uses the DefaultConnection from the appsettings.json file.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make accessing your app data easier just put it in well known folder. Based on your application name I assume that your app is a desktop one and stores user specific data in SQLite DB which should be accessible from different computers. Than location of DB should be determined as:

```
    var sqlitePath = Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), 
        @"<YourAppName>\todo.db");
```

This simplifies all application data management and makes location of the data on all computers users may be using consistent disregard of the way application is installed. Furthermore this guarantees that user will have full access rights to DB folder. In case your project has other functional requirements data location should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: I had to check if the directory was created before using.

if (!Directory.Exists(sqlitePath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(sqlitePath);

optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + sqlitePath + "\\CtxName.db");